# Show that limit of $n(1-(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2})^p)$ as $n\to\infty$ is $\frac{p}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For proving the convergence of the following series
$$\frac{1}{2}^p+\frac{1\times3}{2\times4}^p+\frac{1\times3\times5}{2\times4\times6}^p+.... \text{ for } p>2$$

I try to use Rabe test to establish the convergence (by showing the limit below is greater than 1)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1-(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2})^p)$$

but when I trying to evaluate the limit, I face a dead end.
Therefore, I wonder whether anyone can help with this problem or giving me some hints.

By using Wolfram Alpha, the limit equal to $p/2$, which is consistence with convergence of series for $p>2$. Hope this could be useful.

Comment: Are you familiar with generalized Binomial Theorem? You can write $\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}$ as $(1- \frac{1}{2n+2})$

Comment: Try using L'Hopital's rule by first writing the expression as ${1-({2n+1\over 2n+2})^p\over 1/n}$

Comment: Thank you for you two suggestion. I am able to finish it with generalized binomial theorem. But I wonder am I making any mistake when using L'Hopital to $\frac{1-\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}^p}{1/n}$ since I getting a limit with $\frac{p}{2}$ and something like $n^2\times...$

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward way to compute the limit in question would be to use the Taylor approximation for $(1+x)^p$ when $|x| <1$. Indeed, using the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Binomial_series) for $(1+x)^p$, where $|x|<1$ we have
$$
(1 + x)^p =  1 + px + O(x^2) \tag{1}.
$$
Using $(1)$ for $n$ large we get
$$
\left(   \frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \right)^p = \left( 1 -  \frac{1}{2n+2} \right)^p = 1 - p\frac{1}{2n+2} + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right),
$$
hence 
$$
n \left[ 1  - \left(   \frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \right)^p \right]=    n p \frac{1}{2n+2} + O\left(\frac 1n \right) \to \frac p2, \ \ \text{ as } n \to \infty.
$$